# How to use scipy.interpolate to get sequential point interpolation?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I used scipy.interpolate to draw interpolation curves between points

Here is the python code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

x =np.array([1,2,3,4,3,2])
y = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2])
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y,kind='linear')
xnew = np.arange(1, 4, 0.01)
ynew = f(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, ynew, '-')
plt.show()
```

and I get this figure
[image]

But I would like to get this one
[image]

How this can be achieved ?

Comment: If you change line 7 of your code to `f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y,,kind='linear',assume_sorted = True,fill_value="extrapolate")` and check your resulting graph you will notice that your xnew and ynew are sorted in range from 0 - 4.

Comment: Yeah I see that but in that case again I don't get the desired graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [interpolate.splrep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy.interpolate.splrep) to interpolate a parametric curve. As described in the Scipy reference page about [Interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html). Add parameter k=1 to get a linear spline fit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

x =np.array([1,2,3,4,3,2])
y = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2])
tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0., k=1)
unew = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
out = interpolate.splev(unew, tck)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', out[0], out[1], '-')
plt.show()
```

[image]